# Function: zeroes, extreme values and inflection points

Tags: calculus, functions

I have the following function $$y=2x-e^{-2}$$ and how can I calculate the zeroes, extreme values, types of extreme values and inflections points.

I have done similar examples but they were without the $e$, so this confuses me a little.

Can someone please explain me how to do this, thanks.

Comment: it is a linear function,$e$ is constant, don't afraid go ahead

Comment: @haqnatural I tried doing it, but I'm not sure about the result, so that's why I would like someone to do it and explain me a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=2x-e^{-2}$ is the equation of a line with slope $2$ and $y$-intercept at $-\frac 1{e^2}$.

$y' = 2$ which is precisely the slope of $y$, but since $y' = 2\neq 0$ there are no extrema.  However, if  $y=2x-e^{-2}$ is defined only on an interval of reals given by $x\in \{a, b\}$ with $a\lt b$, and the line has positive slope, it is an always increasing function. So if it is constrained to such an interval, then at $x=a$ we'd have a minimum, and at $x = b$ we'd have a maximum.

When $x = 0$ we find the point where $y = (2(0) -\frac 1{e^2}$, which is the y-intercept we found above.

And when $y = 0$, we have $x= \frac{1}{2e^2}$

Answer (score 1):

The function you wrote down it's just a translation of $y=2x$.

Zeros: $y=0 \implies 2x-e^{-2} = 0$ from which you have $x=\frac{1}{2e^2}$.

Limits: $$\lim_{x\to\ \pm \infty} 2x-e^{-2} = \pm \infty$$

And, obviously, if you derive the function you obtain $y'=2$ so you don't have maxs and mins. And, easily, you see there are not inflection points.